# What software implements the multiple comparison sign test?

Tags: multiple-comparisons, sign-test

What software implements the multiple comparison sign test as described in Steel (1959)?

#### References

- Steel, R.G.D. (1959). A multiple comparison sign test: treatments versus control. Journal of the American Statistical Association, , 767-775. [PDF](http://sci2s.ugr.es/keel/pdf/algorithm/articulo/1959-JSTOR-Steel.pdf)

Comment: Which software are you using? Googling around let me find out that SYSTAT and SPSS in version 11.5 seem to have built in the Steel–Dwass–Critchlow–Fligner-test, an generalization of the test in your reference. There is an SUGI paper by Paul Juneau that mentiones a SAS macro called %DSCF that computes the test and can obviously only obtained by contacting the author.

Comment: I wonder whether this is not simply the same think as a pairwise Wilcoxon rank test? If this is the case, one such test is implemented in R (in the default bundle) under the function pairwise.wilcox.test()

Comment: @user603 That's a good guess, but those tests are not the same.  The closest test that's widely implemented appears to be the [Kruskal-Wallis test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%E2%80%93Wallis_one-way_analysis_of_variance) followed by some form of nonparametric multiple comparisons.